# Adjustable lambda to different lists

Tags: python

I am sorting different lists. For example:

One list has 3 integers: [[3, 4, 2], [3, 5, 3]]

The other has 4: [[3, 4, 2, 4], [3, 5,3 ,2]]

Like this there are more, ranging from two to five integers.

I could do this manually for every list, but since I'm still learning I could ask how this is done automatically!

So I have this code for rearranging the list in descending order

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]], reverse = True)
```

This would work for the second example, but for the first example it would give:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So my thought was something like this:

```
key = lambda x: [x[i] for i in range(len(l[0]))]
```

but it didn't work..

Does anybody knows if in this situation you can have an adjustable lambda?

Comment: `l.sort(key=lambda x: [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]], reverse = True)` could just be `l.sort(reverse=True)`, no? Lists are already sorted lexicographically. And you could sort the second one the same way. I really don't understand what you mean by "adjustable lambda". A lambda is *just a function* like any other, created with a lambda expression instead of a `def` statement.

Comment: I think what you were looking for is something like `key = lambda x: [x[i] for i in range(len(x))]` althoug really, you shouldn't use indices, and just do `lambda x: [i for i in x]` but again, as a sorting key, that is pointless. And *either* of those function could just be written as `lambda x: list(x)` since `[item for item in iterable]` is always just `list(iterable)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wow idd I don't need lambda.. Thanks ..

Comment: One important thing to grok is that you never **need** a lambda. It is a convenience, for when you need a one-off function, often to pass to anther function, and don't care about naming it, so instead of writing out `def sort_key(x): return <whatever>` you can just do `lambda x: <whatever>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I get your question correctly, as you talk about one list in each case but then again show lists looking like lists of lists.

So for the simple case of a normal list, python provides sorting already, you don't need lambda:

```
>>> a = [3,2,7,1,11]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 7, 11]
>>> b = sorted(a, reverse=True)
>>> b
[11, 7, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Check here for more options on sorting: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Now if you have a list of lists, you could go for something like this:

```
>>> a = [[1,5,2],[3,4,1]]
>>> a
[[1, 5, 2], [3, 4, 1]]
>>> for idx,ls in enumerate(a):
    a[idx] = sorted(ls, reverse=True)

    
>>> a
[[5, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1]]
```

which you could then use in a map function if you wanted to use a lambda:

```
>>> a = [[1,5,2],[3,4,1]]
>>> b = map(lambda x: sorted(x, reverse=True),a)
>>> b
<map object at 0x03C0F220>
>>> list(b)
[[5, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1]]
>>>
```

Note to put the list keyword infront of the map object to make it a list.